# How can I close tabs to the left in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Google Chrome has a button to "close tabs to the right" (right click on a tab), but not one for the left.

Firstly, why is this?

Secondly, how do I add a button to close tabs to the left?

I've looked through the Google Chrome Support, and couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this extension: [Close Tabs to Left](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/close-tabs-to-the-left/gcmjpicopfkgmjdomahfjkmhpcelklba)

> Too many tabs opened? Chrome allows to close all tabs to the right, close all tabs but current. But what about all tabs to the left? Tabs to the left are often was open earlier. This extension will help you to close already unnecessary tabs. Just click on extension's icon to close 'em.

Comment: I can't believe Chrome is such a junk browser. A few years ago Maxthon had close to left to right and other useful stuff out of box, but their rendering started to suck. Firefox has plugins to be part of context menu, so you have "close to left" in same menu as "close to right" but of course in chrome not possible all plugins a button next to search bar or context menu of webpage, so inconsistent

Comment: This is why I loved the old opera and vivaldi.  They had features like closing tabs and being able to navigate selecting web elements on the page using shift + arrow keys.  But normies always jump on the band wagons.  Chrome marketed, normies flocked in.

Answer (score 12):

> **Firstly why is this**

I've always assumed this because it is useful to clean up after using middle-button to open lots of Google results. I find it useful. Since new tabs are to the right (and not to the left) of the current tab, this makes sense.

> **how do I add a button to close tabs to the left.**

I don't know. However you can select a group of tabs using click and shift-click and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

Comment: very nice indeed the group of tabs thingy!

Answer (score 6):

Another workaround ... You can multi-select tabs then Ctrl-W to close them all: Select the first tab then shift-click the last tab just before the one you want to keep open, then Ctrl-W.

Answer (score 3):

You can select tabs that you need by press [**Ctrl** + click] on tabs which you want to leave on a pane. And after drag it to left part of pane. And use "close tabs to the right".

It's not a solution for your problem but not bad walkaround.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you can do that!

Answer (score 1):

Use the extension:

[image] [**Close Left Tabs**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/close-left-tabs/mbflckojhjfboffiknejjmmnoipndeab?hl=en)

> Close Left Tabs on one click
>
> Makes your life easier by closing all tabs on left with one press of a button.
> Does not close Pinned Tabs.
> Has a context menu option as well, simply right-click and select from the menu to close left tabs.
>
> No ads, [completely open-source.](https://github.com/Zohaib-Amir/CloseLeftTabs)

Unlike the [extension suggested in this other answer](https://superuser.com/a/467341/10259), it will *not* close pinned tabs (which Chrome puts to the left of the non-pinned tabs).